# Extended Runtime Sessions in watchOS stops working after first run

Tags: delegates, swiftui, watchos, watchos-6

I have some troubles with WKExtendedRuntimeSession.

1. I have set the `WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate` in my ExtensionDelegate
2. I start the session when the app is active with `.start()`
3. I stop sessions by using `session.invalidate()`

When I start it again I get the following error:

`-[WKExtendedRuntimeSession _start]:308: Unable to start sessions because state == WKExtendedRuntimeSessionStateInvalid. notifying delegate <MYAPP_Extension.ExtensionDelegate: 0x17e663d0>. Error is (null)`

**CODE**

My Extension Delegate

```
var session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate {

    func extendedRuntimeSession(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession, didInvalidateWith reason: WKExtendedRuntimeSessionInvalidationReason, error: Error?) {
        print("Session stopped at", Date())
    }

    func extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print("Session started at", Date())
    }

    func extendedRuntimeSessionWillExpire(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {

        session.delegate = self
    }
```

My start happens by `.onAppear(perform:{ session.start() })`

Cancelation:

```
func cancelNow() {
        self.timer.connect().cancel()
        session.invalidate()
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple docs:

> After calling invalidate(), you can no longer run the session. Create and start a new session instead.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextendedruntimesession/3131065-invalidate

So do this:

```
var session: WKExtendedRuntimeSession!

private func startSession() {
    session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
    session.delegate = self
    session.start()
}
```